# Custom Code Behind for DataSet

Tags: asp.net, dataset, code-behind

I used to be able to double-click the work area of a dataset to create and load a code-behind page for it, where i could define some custom code to modify or extend the functionality.

I don't know if it's because I'm using VS 2008, but now that doesn't happen, and the only file "beneath" the xsd file is the xss code which is auto-generated and I don't want to touch.

how do I create that associated code-behind file for the dataset?

thanks!

Comment: There should be a DataSet.cs file you can open.

Comment: I've tried right-clicking->View Code on both the dataset file in the solution explore, on the dataset workspace, and on the various table elements defined in the dataset, they all point to a large xml file with the dataset schema (which has the same name as the xsd designer view)

I'm trying to figure out how to access (or create) the custom .cs file for the dataset

Comment: the .cs file is not present, there is only an xss file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turns out this is only available if the dataset is in a separate class library.

lame.

Answer (score 0):

Right click in the DataSet's design surface and select 'View Code' from the menu that appears.

Comment: I tried that, it brings up a large xml file, not the .cs codebehind file